# What is the correct conjugation of the verb fill in this sentence? Could you please explain grammar in this sentence?

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, writing

A) Inflation is once again a major concern, violent crimes is on the rise, cases of corruption **filling the press,** healthcare in precarious state, insfrastructure projet not materialized and street traffic is depressingly worst than ever. or,

B) Inflation is once again a major concern, violent crime is on the rise, cases of corruption fill the press, healthcare is in a precarious state, infrastructure projects have not materialized and street traffic is depressingly worse than ever.

Comment: *Fill/ing the press is not idiomatic* (and it doesn't make sense) but the verb should match the tense of the other verbs in the sentence ("is a concern", "is on the rise", "is in a precarious state", "have not materialized", "is worse than ever").

Comment: **worse than ever** not *worst*.  "Filling the news" would be idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option B is more correct because the verb tenses match in each clause (they are  present tense). Furthermore, in option B, all clauses are independent (they could stand alone as individual sentences). Using the gerund "filling" makes the clause "cases of corruption filling the press" a dependent clause, which could be technically correct (it could be providing additional details about the previous clause), but it doesn't sound as good because it breaks the list-like flow of the sentence.

Note also that "violent crime is on the rise" is correct while "violent crimes is on the rise" is not correct.